# iOS implement pathfinding/collision detection using the GPU, not the CPU?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, collision-detection, xamarin, path-finding

I'm developing an iOS game.  I've successfully implemented A* pathfinding and a basic collision detection.  The pathfinding works great, but the collision detection I implemented proved to be a little "mediocre" in terms of performance.  *Without getting into any details with regards to my exact implementation*, I'm wondering the following:

Is it possible to implement Pathfinding AND Collision Detection using the iOS device's GPU?  Or at least rely heavily on it...  My current implementation uses the CPU and it would be nice to pass that load off else where if possible.

Anybody know of any GPU functionality available that would help me make collision detection decisions?  Is it possible to leave current A* pathfinding implementation on the CPU and assist with collision detection using the GPU?

Thanks in advance.

**Additional information, my extent of using the iOS GPU is using CoreImage and CIFilters..

Comment: [This program](https://github.com/Moodstocks/sift-gpu-iphone) offloads some computations to the GPU, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: I'd use a physics engine for that. `Chipmunk` e.g. give really good 2d perfs, even if it does not run on the gpu

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Guys.  I ended up making some big optimizations to my movement functions.  This freed up a lot of CPU usage which should allow my collision detection to have more CPU time without lagging the game. I do plan on using an engine for future games, but this game is so unique that I decided against it for this one.